Cortex M0+ Bootloader Passing Top Address in RAM to App For Stack Pointer Address - Correct?
I have a Cortex M0+ device I have developed a bootloader and application for, partially based on some sample code from the IC manufacturer. In the bootloader, just before jumping to the app, the bootloader retrieves an address for the stack pointer and the reset vector of the app. I have verified using the map file of the app that the address is correct. However, the stack pointer address it gets is the topmost address in RAM (0x20008000 in this case). My understanding is the Cortex stack (at least for the "lower" devices like the M0) grows down. I just wanted to confirm that this is the address one should expect to be used for the stack pointer in this scenario.

You can use the linker script file to locate the stack where you want.  A stack at the end of RAM growing down can corrupt data in RAM if it overflows (fails mysteriously).  Consider putting the stack at the beginning of RAM so that an overflow is outside the range of RAM and will cause a hard fault (fails clearly).  See this article for more info https://www.state-machine.com/are-we-shooting-ourselves-in-the-foot-with-stack-overflow.

@kkrambo if you do that you can't use your MPU to fault on Null pointer dereferences (or near NULL pointer dereferences (i.e. ptr->member when ptr is NULL)

I'd be surprised if that were the top most address rather than top-most + 1.  The last byte address I suggest is 0x20007FFFF. The value you have is however correct, if for example a 32-bit register is pushed to the stack, SP is decremented then the register stored.

This isn't a feature of the particular Cortex CPU. All ARM CPUs (including Cortex) support both ascending and descending stacks, as well as "full" and "empty" stacks.
An "ascending" stack grows up from low memory addresses to higher memory addresses. Conversely, a "descending" stack grows from high memory addresses, down to lower addresses.
A "full" stack is one where the stack pointer points to a memory location that contains data, and the stack pointer needs to be modified (incremented or decremented) before storing the next value.
An "empty" stack is where the stack pointer is already pointing at the next free space. To push data, you store it at the current stack pointer, then modify the stack pointer.
This is all described here, and includes this:

The Procedure Call Standard for the ARM Architecture (AAPCS), and the ARM and Thumb C and C++ compilers always use a full descending stack.
The PUSH and POP instructions assume a full descending stack. They are the preferred synonyms for STMDB and LDM with writeback.

So having the initial stack pointer pointing to the end of RAM is what you would expect, as the stack must grow downwards.


However, the stack pointer address it gets is the topmost address in RAM (0x20008000 in this case). My understanding is the Cortex stack (at least for the "lower" devices like the M0) grows down. I just wanted to confirm that this is the address one should expect to be used for the stack pointer in this scenario.

It is not pedantically correct.
Cortex M class processors (at least the one's I've used) fetch the reset vector/address from the 1st index of the vector table (usually at 0x0000_0000, but not always) and the stack pointer from the 0th index of the vector table.
Where the stack is located, however, is controlled by the linker descriptor file used when the ELF is linked.  It might be at the end of internal/fast memory.  It might be at the end of slower memory.  It might be stuck wherever works well for the application based on the target SoC.
Your interim tool to convert ELF->bootfile needs to do the work to parse the ELF to get the right addresses and put whatever bootloader "command" into the your bootfile to properly set up the stack pointer before jumping to the reset vector.
And because you never know where the image to load will populate, you have to make sure your bootloader can deal with that or ensure the applications are linked to not stomp on the bootloader.
